# Drag & Drop: How to prevent folders in my Dock to pop up as windows?

Tags: macos, dock, ui

I have a folder in my dock where I want to drop files. When hovering over the icon, the folder always pops up as new Finder window. I want it to be a stack or a list. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can control-click on the folder and choose stack or list but that affects how it is shown when you click on it. I think you're talking about spring-loading and the control-click settings do not seem to affect this.

Comment: Yes, I know and tried all three of these settings, they seem to have no effect for drag and drop.

Comment: Might it, by any chance be a smart folder? If so then there is no way around this.

Comment: No, it's not a smart folder, so I keep my hopes up.

Answer (score 1):

In Finder preferences (<kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> from Finder itself), unchecking "Spring-loaded folders and windows" will prevent a window from opening up when dragging files to a folder.

Comment: AFAIK this has no affect on **dock** folders, and the Finder window that appears when adding a file to such a folder.

Comment: This prevents the folders in my Dock from popping up at all. So I could only copy/move into the parent folder. I need to drop files into the child folders.